# Save log file in a relative path from .properties file

Tags: java, log4j, relative-path, properties-file

I have a .properties file that defines the path in which my logfile is being saved. The question is simple but I'm struggling to find the solution. My directory looks like this:

```
   -MyBundle
     --configuration
           config.properties
     --log
           logfile.log
     --src
```

How can I define the path to "`logfile`" inside the `config.properties` file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you dont have permission to write to that directory. Either change permissions on the directory or install the software in a folder somewhere else where you do have permissions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logFile.log` is at `"../log/logFile.log"` relative to `"config.properties"`

The `..` notation references the directory that contains `.`, which is the current directory.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: Do you have permission to write files to this directory?

Answer (score 1):

In case your bundle is executed as a separated process, let suppose it would be a .jar file;
you should access to relative path considering the "current working directory".

In your case I suppose, "log/logFile.log" should be set in the configuration file.

Futhermore, I would point out you can know you "current working directory" by checking system property [user.dir](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29)

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```